# how to resolve the optimization issue

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have two different sequences and want to extract similar patterns within them. How can I do that? what this problem is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [Sequence Alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) algorithm. These are often used in bioinformatics to align DNA sequences, but can be used for any sequences. Instead of measuring the difference between two adjacent items (which you would do if you were comparing DNA), the "difference" penalty is the value of the weight between adjacent items.

There are several algorithms for this purpose, you can find find a few of them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Sequence_alignment_algorithms).